# Do the deviations in the intro always relate to the episode?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

When the series begin, there is a really short intro screen, which shows the logo of the series. In every episode there is a small deviation which shows some characters.

I have assumption that these deviations may tell about the episode. For example in S01E17 "Hat Trick" you can see some mushrooms in the intro screen. Spoiler:

> In this episode the Mad Hatter is being introduced, who has sold mushrooms to live his humble life.
>  Or when Red Riding Hood is being introduced, you can see a shrouded and disguised human on the intro screen.

But then sometimes there are deviations I can't connect to one episode. Or deviations that don't really refer to a important character in that episode. Like:

> In S01E20 Pinocchio is being introduced. The intro screen shows Jiminy Cricket again - he appears in that episode but has nothing to do but saying two line of unimportant text.

[image]
*Sample screen, where the unicorn is the deviation - which I haven't understood yet.*

Or maybe I'm just not seing that hint. So that leads me to my question:

**Do these deviations in the intro screen always refer to one important character or can they be placed randomly?**

Comment: Here's an (old/incomplete) refresher on [a whole bunch of the titlecards for the series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=osq8wpz5l2A)

Comment: The unicorn is Maleficent's unicorn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort of.  From the [Once Upon a Time wikia](http://onceuponatime.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_Title_Cards):

> The Episode Titlecards feature a character, creature, location or item featured (or not) in the episode.

In particular, it looks like the first season was semi-random - for example, the unicorn in the first episode was probably more to catch the eye of viewers, than it was to be about the episode itself. As of Season 2, they become relevant to the episode:

> Every episode of Season Two feature a title card tailored to the episode. Two images from Season One, that of Red Riding Hood and that of Rumplestiltskin's Spinning Wheel, have been reused, along with twenty new slides.

And looking at the list for Season Three, it appears that (at least so far) they remain relevant to the episode.

Comment: Ah ok, so they got requests from the users with questions like mine and then they implemented it. :D Thank you!

Comment: From the very beginning the title card always showed something featured in the episode.  The unicorn, for instance, is Maleficent's pet unicorn.